# Retrieving progress of Direct Upload using youtube gdata API

Tags: php, upload, youtube, progress, zend-gdata

I'm following along with the documentation about using the gData Youtube API for doing direct uploads with PHP.  I can successfully upload videos, so thats all well and good.  The part I'm having trouble figuring out, if its even possible is getting some upload progress status as in percent complete or number of bytes uploaded.

Here is the snippet of code where the upload happens.

```
 <?php 
try {
      $newEntry = $yt->insertEntry($myVideoEntry, $uploadUrl, 'Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoEntry');
    } catch (Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException $httpException) {
      echo $httpException->getRawResponseBody();
    } catch (Zend_Gdata_App_Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

Anyone have any ideas how to update a `$progess` variable or something as this is uploading?

Answer (score 5):

Demo url:--

http://jquery.malsup.com/form/progress.html

You can download jquery file below url and add in html tag

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js

http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js

Try this:--

output video:-

[image]

This is my video.php file

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<title>File Upload Progress Demo #1</title>
<style>
body { padding: 30px }
form { display: block; margin: 20px auto; background: #eee; border-radius: 10px; padding: 15px }

.progress { position:relative; width:400px; border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 1px; border-radius: 3px; }
.bar { background-color: #B4F5B4; width:0%; height:20px; border-radius: 3px; }
.percent { position:absolute; display:inline-block; top:3px; left:48%; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>File Upload Progress Demo #1</h1>
    <code>&lt;input type="file" name="myfile"></code>
        <form action="video_upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="uploadedfile"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload File to Server">
    </form>

    <div class="progress">
        <div class="bar"></div >
        <div class="percent">0%</div >
    </div>

    <div id="status"></div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script>
(function() {

var bar = $('.bar');
var percent = $('.percent');
var status = $('#status');

$('form').ajaxForm({
    beforeSend: function() {
        status.empty();
        var percentVal = '0%';
        bar.width(percentVal)
        percent.html(percentVal);
    },
    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
        var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
        bar.width(percentVal)
        percent.html(percentVal);
    },
    complete: function(xhr) {
        bar.width("100%");
        percent.html("100%");
        status.html(xhr.responseText);
    }
}); 

})();       
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

this is my video_upload.php file

```
<?php
// video_upload.php


require_once 'Zend/Loader.php'; // the Zend dir must be in your include_path
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_YouTube');
$yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube();

// Define the authentication that will be used
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin'); 

// Authenticate
$authenticationURL= 'https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin';
$httpClient = 
  Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient(
              $username = "USERNAME",
              $password = "PASSWORD",
              $service = 'youtube',
              $client = null,
              $source = 'HTML SOURCE CODE SNIPPET',
              $loginToken = null,
              $loginCaptcha = null,
              $authenticationURL);

$applicationId = 'YOUR APPLICATION ID';
$clientId = 'Upload videos to youtube using the youtube API';
$developerKey = 'YOUR DEVELOPER KEY';
$yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube($httpClient, $applicationId, $clientId, $developerKey);



// create a new VideoEntry object
$myVideoEntry = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoEntry();

$myVideoEntry->setVideoTitle($videoTitle);
$myVideoEntry->setVideoDescription($VideoDescription);
// The category must be a valid YouTube category!
$myVideoEntry->setVideoCategory($VideoCategory);

// Set keywords. Please note that this must be a comma-separated string
// and that individual keywords cannot contain whitespace
$myVideoEntry->SetVideoTags($VideoTags);

$tokenHandlerUrl = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/action/GetUploadToken';
$tokenArray = $yt->getFormUploadToken($myVideoEntry, $tokenHandlerUrl);
$tokenValue = $tokenArray['token'];
$postUrl = $tokenArray['url'];


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $postUrl."?nexturl=http://YOUR_WEBPAGE.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
// same as <input type="file" name="file">
$post = array("file"=>"@".$VideoFile['tmp_name'], "token"=>$tokenValue);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post); 
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);

echo $info;

?>
```