# Can I use a single Google account for Youtube Data API?

Tags: php, laravel-4, youtube, youtube-data-api

I have two questions about the Youtube api

1. I made a testing site with videos hosted on Youtube. I go through the Oauth2 connection and choose the account to login to. Problem is I may want to give permission to other users to change videos. I don't want them to choose the youtube account if they need to be authorized again. Is it possible to hard code what account I am going to use because I only want one? Maybe I shouldn't use Oauth2, I don't know.
2. I am making the upload and delete calls from the api in a controller called by a `Post` request. It seems like it takes a long time to upload and get the id back. Should I be doing some in the background or really wait for the upload? All I'm using is a gif, I don't know how to get percent done of the upload for an uploading bar. But it would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your app is basically impersonating that youtube (google) account.  If you want to give people the ability to change data as themselves, they will need to login as themselves and have permissions granted to them.  But in either case, they'll only be able to update content your "app" is giving the permissions to.
2. Here is an example of what you are describing: [Retrieving progress of Direct Upload using youtube gdata API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419451/retrieving-progress-of-direct-upload-using-youtube-gdata-api)